# jQuery styles not being applied to its elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following code. Consider the following question, why stuff inside `#d1` isn't getting styles from "command", I've tried using `.addClass` functions too, to show my menu. This following project is dropdown menu. If I add `("alert("hello");")`, it will print out that message, although it will never apply those styles or classes. Why is that?

```js
    $('#d1').click(function () {
   $(this).attr('style', 'display: block!important');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-list {
        display: none;
    }
    .active {
    color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
            <div class="logo">LOGO</div> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="d1" href="#">Projects</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-list" onclick="myFunction(this)">                    
                    <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Movies</a></li>
                    <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Slow-mo</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a id="d2" href="#">About me</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-list">                    
                        <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Phone</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are adding the styling to the #d1, not the `ul` after it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to target the `next()` ul that you want to show.

```js
//get a reference to all the links
var $dropdownLinks = $('.dropdown-link');

//bind the click handler to the links.
$dropdownLinks.on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  //remove the active class from the other links
  $dropdownLinks.not(this).removeClass('active');
  //toggle the active class on this element so it can open or close
  $this.toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
//make the link red if active
.dropdown-link.active {
  color: red;
}

//hide the immediately following sibling dropdown-list element
//of the dropdown-link, so long as it is not active
.dropdown-link:not(.active) + .dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active dropdown-link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="d1" class="dropdown-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-list" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Slow-mo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="d2" class="dropdown-link" href="#">About me</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-list">
        <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">CV</a></li>
        <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Phone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works flawless. To be honest, I was playing with "closest" variable, so I was on the almost right track. Thank you again

Comment: Np, and (I don't know if you were going to do this already or not) take note that if you put a common class on both the links, then your selector could change to be that class, and then the code work work for all your links. @Adrian

Comment: I don't quite get that. I got the part "common class" but not the rest

Comment: `<a id="d1" href="#">` could be `<a id="d1" class="dropdown-link" href="#">` or something.  Same with the `d2` link.  Then your script changes from `$('#d1').click(` to `$('.dropdown-link').click(` and then it would work with both of them.  @Adrian

Comment: I'm really sorry for this question after question but seems like I can't get my head around it. I'm trying to do mobile menu style, when you click on a link it drops down when you do it again it hides, do you perhaps know how to get this thing working? Same code as before, I tried removeClass, jQuery animations(slidedown and up), hide and much more ;( I'd understand if no ;)

Comment: @Adrian ok, I've updated my answer to include the version that uses the common class, and the logic for opening and closing the menu.  I've included comments in the javascript and the css.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
$('ul li a').click(function (){
   $("ul li > a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   if($(this).next('.dropdown-list').length != 0){
        $(this).next('.dropdown-list').slideToggle();
   }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-list {
        display: none;
 }
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
   <div class="logo">LOGO</div> 
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
       <li><a id="d1" href="#">Projects</a>
           <ul class="dropdown-list">                    
                  <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Movies</a></li>
                    <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Slow-mo</a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a id="d2" href="#">About me</a>
           <ul class="dropdown-list">                    
                        <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a style="line-height: 0;" href="#">Phone</a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Why hard stuff is so simple, lol. I wasn't aware of length variable, I'm glad you helped me to discover it! :D Thanks :D

Comment: It's ok!
Also if any query related to this so please ask me i've help you anytime :)